# How to play a 'disc image file' in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: media-player

How do I watch a 4GB film in 'disc image file' format on my computer?  I tried VLC but only one "extras" clip is working but without any audio and when I click on any other options on the home screen nothing happens.  I thought VLC played everything.

Comment: How do I know what sort of image it is? Also, the thing is I thought I'm only supposed to "Accept" if it helps my problem so it can be useful to others. Most of the answers I got didn't help. Should I "Accept" anyway?

Comment: You're right that you shouldn't, but most people here will see the 10% and decide it's not worth it usually. I'm not at 100% either though. Anyways, is it an ISO, an IMG, a DMG? The file format of the image

Comment: Under type in Explorer it says: disc image file.

Comment: Oh, under Properties it says: .img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what this `Disc image file` is.

VLC has some success opening some image files directly, but, I have known it to fail sometimes for unknown reasons.

Why it is failing in your case - I can't honestly say without a lot more information.

Providing this is a standard image file, I would recommend downloading [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) then mounting the disk through that, so, it appears to the computer that you have inserted that disk for real - then relaunch VLC choosing the (virtual) drive instead of the file.

If it works - great, it was one of the many VLC bugs that seems to be happening lately. If it still doesn't work - it could simply be that a codec is missing from your machine that is required to play it.

Depending on what codec it is, you may have some luck installing the [K-Lite Codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

I would think it is more a case of codec missing - especially if the disk is high definition or has some similar special features (3d etc.).

Comment: How can I tell what kind of image file it is?

Comment: Awesome. Virtual Clone Drive made it work in VLC!